# Sum of specific row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some query like this

`SELECT TotalAmount/(select DateDiff(dd,StartDate, DateAdd(dd, 1,EndDate)))
 AS TotalAmountForMonth
FROM Campaign 
WHERE StartDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
  AND StartDate <  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 1)`

This query search this month's campaigns and gets daily payment from TotalAmount as row. But I need their sum(total) number.

Question is , How can i get sum of this query?

Edit1:
 table example

`Total Amount                 StartDate                       EndDate
1980                 2018-05-01 00:00:00.0000000    2018-05-31 00:00:00.0000000 
1271                 2018-05-01 00:00:00.0000000    2018-06-01 00:00:00.0000000 
2015                 2018-05-01 00:00:00.0000000    2018-06-01 00:00:00.0000000 
238                  2018-05-01 00:00:00.0000000    2018-05-08 00:00:00.0000000 
0                    2018-05-01 00:00:00.0000000    2018-06-01 00:00:00.0000000`

And their result

`63,8709677419355
39,71875
62,96875
29,75
0`

Comment: Can you just Clarify the requirement

Comment: What is with that bizarre division in there? I can't for the life of me understand the point of taking TotalAmount / datediff....what are you trying to do? This would be a good place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require [SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_sum.asp) aggregate function.

```
Select SUM(TotalAmountForMonth) from (
SELECT TotalAmount/(select DateDiff(dd,StartDate, DateAdd(dd, 1,EndDate)))
 AS TotalAmountForMonth
FROM Campaign 
WHERE StartDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
  AND StartDate <  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 1)
)
```

Comment: Can you clarify the requirements with some sample data and output

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) aggregate function.

To keep the code clean, I would use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to encapsulate your query and `SUM` the results as follows:

```
;with totalAmountForMonth (
    SELECT TotalAmount/(select DateDiff(dd,StartDate, DateAdd(dd, 1,EndDate)))
     AS TotalAmountForMonth
    FROM Campaign 
    WHERE StartDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
      AND StartDate <  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 1);
)

select 
    sum(TotalAmontForMonth) as SumTotalAmount
from
    totalAmountForMonth;
```